# Set specific instance of duplicated icon colour

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-tablayout

Before you read on I know that to change a specific tab icons colour I can use

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(i).getIcon().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorInactive), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

and there are many duplicated answers for how to specifically do this - but they don't answer my problem.

I have a toolbar in which a person might have the sam icon twice (e.g. they have two or more employees profiles they can view), the problem is that by getting the icon and setting the colour it changes the colour for all the icons, not the selected icon - presumably because get icon just selects the icon by id rather than the specific instance

[image]

If I select a tab with a different icon (e.g. more) then they both reset.

Is there are way to only target the specific instance of the icon when changing the colour without creating a new drawable icon?

Comment: Please check [This](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation) link. I think this might help you.

Comment: @Ajay-Rlogical - thanks, this would be really great but for security with our app we can only add in trusted dependancies.  Is there a way to achieve a similar effect with just the build in android libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not apparent from the code, but the bitmaps that underlie the icons are shared. See [`BitmapDrawable#mutate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#mutate()) about the sharing of bitmaps.

> A mutable BitmapDrawable still shares its Bitmap with any other Drawable that comes from the same resource.

But we will be able to separate out the color of the icon by calling `mutate()` on it.

Here is a short method that shows how to separate out one icon from two others that rely on the same drawable resource:

```
    private void setupTabIcons() {
        int sharedIcon = R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite;

        Drawable inactiveIcon = getResources().getDrawable(sharedIcon);

        // Separate out the first icon so changes don't propagate to other icons.
        inactiveIcon.mutate();
        inactiveIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorInactive),
                                    android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        // We could also do the following for Lollipop+:
//         inactiveIcon.setTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorInactive));
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(inactiveIcon);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(sharedIcon);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(sharedIcon);
    }
```

[image]